# Accessing properties from Mappers

Tags: sql-server, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a linked server in SQL Server so when I query something, it has to be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [SERVERNAME].[DBNAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
```

Now I have to implement this way of querying to an existing project with the `servername`, `dbname` and `schema` provided in my `application.properties`.

Is there any way to access these properties from my Mapper(xml)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [properties](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties).
With [MyBatis-Spring-Boot](http://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/), you can define properties in your `application.properties` with the prefix `mybatis.configuration.variables.` [1].

```
mybatis.configuration.variables.db_servername=YOUR_SERVER_NAME
mybatis.configuration.variables.db_dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME
mybatis.configuration.variables.db_schema=YOUR_SCHEMA
```

It is also possible to reference variables defined in the same `application.properties`.

```
mybatis.configuration.variables.db_servername=${servername}
mybatis.configuration.variables.db_dbname=${dbname}
mybatis.configuration.variables.db_schema=${schema}
```

Then you can use these variables in mappers using `${}`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM [${db_servername}].[${db_dbname}].[${db_schema}].[TABLE]
```

Note: `#{}` won't work. See this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the difference.

[1] The doc says that the prefix is `mybatis.configuration-properties.`, but I just tested it and it didn't work. It could be my mistake, though. I plan to investigate when I have some spare time.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Will update if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties

```
mybatis.configuration-properties.tablesSchema=foo
```

In mapper.xml

```
select * from ${tablesSchema}.bar
```

> configuration-properties
>
> Externalized properties for MyBatis configuration. Specified
> properties can be used as placeholder on MyBatis config file and
> Mapper file. For detail see the MyBatis reference page.
>
> configuration.*
>
> Property keys for Configuration bean provided by MyBatis Core. About
> available nested properties see the MyBatis reference page. NOTE: This
> property cannot be used at the same time with the config-location.

See https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

[Troubleshooting Tips]

- Check the bean of `MybatisProperties.configurationProperties` to make sure your property has been loaded.
- If you create your own `SqlSessionFactory` bean, don't forget to call `SqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigurationProperties(MybatisProperties)` in that bean method.